# Extract fields from nested json (from json response) in python 2.7

Tags: python, json

I am extracting information from an API. I am unable to extract the nested fields from the json response. Below is the code and JSON response I am getting from the API.

```
url = www.jkhdöfhpirnl.com/api/v2/articleinfo?
token = api_token=ABCDEG7829848bjbmbsjhgd
x = &pmid
id = "123456"
response_suggestions = requests.get(url + token + x + id)
print (response_suggestions.json()['genes'])
```

```
[{'symbol': 'MTHFR', 'mentions': 2, 'variants': [{'key': 'E433A', 'matched': ['A1298C'], 'mentions': 3, 'cdna_effects': [{'hgvsc': 'NM_005957.4:c.1298A>C', 'rsid': ''}, {'hgvsc': 'NM_005957.1:c.1298A>C', 'rsid': ''}, {'hgvsc': 'NM_005957.2:c.1298A>C', 'rsid': ''}, {'hgvsc': 'NM_005957.3:c.1298A>C', 'rsid': ''}], 'url': 'https://mastermind.genomenon.com/detail?gene=mthfr&mutation=mthfr:E433A'}], 'url': 'https://mastermind.genomenon.com/detail?gene=mthfr'}]
```

I would like to extract value of symbol, mentions, and few fields of variants. For eg.

```
'symbol': 'MTHFR', 'mentions': 2, 'variants': [{'key': 'E433A', 'matched': ['A1298C'], 'mentions': 3
```

How can I do this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have a dictionary in a list. What's the problem accessing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you look closely at the structure of the response to find out at which level the different values are and how you can get there.

The first step is a list in which everything is enclosed `[ ... ]`. Since it has only one element, you can either do `[content] = response` or `content = response[0]` which will have the same effect.

Now you have a dictionary you can work with. If you don't know how, look at some guides/[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You usually don't extract parts of a dictionary anyways, but only retrieve the values you need. Here some examples to get started

```py
symbol_value = content['symbol']
first_variant_key = content['variants'][0]['key']
list_of_cdna_effects = content['variants'][0]['cdna_effects']
```